# "Should never have been" or "should have never been"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Example:

> Methamphetamine should *have* **never** been created.

or

> Methamphetamine should **never** *have* been created.

Which one is correct?

This seems like it should have a simple answer, but either way sounds good to my ear.

Is there an official rule?

EDIT: This is not the same as asking the difference between 'was never' and 'never was.' 'Was' is the past tense form of the infinitive verb 'to be.' In this case, the word 'have' is part of the verb itself. This question essentially involves whether the word 'never' could be added as part of the verb. To clarify and expand the question, it could in fact be said in three different ways:

> should have *never* been
>
> should *never* have been
>
> *never* should have been

Comment: Related: [https://www.englishforums.com/English/WouldNeverWouldNever/dcjrg/post.htm](https://www.englishforums.com/English/WouldNeverWouldNever/dcjrg/post.htm)

Comment: Idiomatically, your second version is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should+have+never+been%2Cshould+never+have+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshould%20have%20never%20been%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshould%20never%20have%20been%3B%2Cc0). But there's no "rule" - it's just a stylistic choice where it so happens nearly everyone makes the *same* choice.

Comment: That's funny, @FumbleFingers, I would use the 1st example since "have never" is more emphatic, especially spoken, than "never have", (to me, of course).

Comment: @Kristina: But do you not have a "gut feel" for the established idiomatic preference, even though *in this specific context* you might choose to override it? The way I see it, there's no specific "rule" here, so we're free to go either way. If you *do* choose to go down the "less-traveled" route, at least some fraction of your audience will (consciously or subconsciously) take that on board. And if they're anything like me they may simply assume your purpose was to add emphasis even though that's not "inherent" in the word order. So it *works* that way, even though there's no actual *reason*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers...exactly! :-)

Comment: @Kristina: I'm pretty sure that specific point came up on ELL a while ago, but I can't find it now. I mean the idea that we always tend to look for some subtle nuance when we encounter a *valid, but not the most common* sequence of words. Which is often a problem for nns because they don't necessarily *know* which of two sequences is more common. Come to that, we native speakers don't always know *consciously*, so on ELL we sometimes end up tying ourselves in knots trying to "explain" how a different order shifts the emphasis when it's just *"unusual sequence" means **pay attention**!*

Comment: ESL teachers have to teach the language in a concise and easily understandable way.  They must choose to teach the form that is used in the vast majority of cases.  That form is your second option.  See FumbleFingers' ngram in the second post above to see how the frequencies compare.  Chances are, many of the usages of the other example are just carelessness, or people using the language who are not that familiar with it.  Some of those usages might also be intentional, but not enough to be concerned with.

Comment: And don’t forget: “*Never should have been.*”

Answer (score -2):

Since the language is arbitrary, I'm not pretty sure that there's ever a syntactic rule or probably pragmatic glasses points out of this thing.

But I would really recommend you the first sentence, since the adverb of frequency used there emphasizes the "negative" form of the sentence indirectly.

It's like using "not" in a normal negative sentence!

Best Regards.